# Making a template helper reactive in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am building a chat application and on my "new chats" page I have a list of contacts, which you can select one by one by tapping them (upon which I apply a CSS selected class and push the user id into an array called 'newChatters'.

I want to make this array available to a helper method so I can display a reactive list of names, with all users who have been added to the chat.

The template that I want to display the reactive list in:

```
<template name="newChatDetails">
  <div class="contactHeader">
    <h2 class="newChatHeader">{{newChatters}}</h2>
  </div>
</template>
```

The click contactItem event triggered whenever a contact is selected:

```
Template.contactsLayout.events({
 'click #contactItem': function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(e.target).toggleClass('selected');
   newChatters.push(this.username);
...
```

The newChatters array is getting updated correctly so up to this point all is working fine. Now I need to make {{newChatters}} update reactively. Here's what I've tried but it's not right and isn't working:

```
Template.newChatDetails.helpers({
  newChatters: function() {
    return newChatters;
  }
});
```

How and where do I use Deps.autorun() to make this work? Do I even need it, as I thought that helper methods auto update on invalidation anyway?

Answer (score 14):

1) Define `Tracker.Dependency` in the same place where you define your object:

```
var newChatters = [];
var newChattersDep = new Tracker.Dependency();
```

2) Use `depend()` before you read from the object:

```
Template.newChatDetails.newChatters = function() {
  newChattersDep.depend();
  return newChatters;
};
```

3) Use `changed()` after you write:

```
Template.contactsLayout.events({
  'click #contactItem': function(e, t) {
    ...
    newChatters.push(...);
    newChattersDep.changed();
  },
});
```

Comment: You just relieved hours of frustration. Thanks lakenen!

Answer (score 6):

You should use the `Session` object for this.

```
Template.contactsLayout.events({
 'click #contactItem': function (e) {
   //...
   newChatters.push(this.username);
   Session.set('newChatters', newChatters);
 }
});
```

and then

```
Template.newChatDetails.helpers({
  newChatters: function() {
    return Session.get('newChatters');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a local `Meteor.Collection` cursor as a reactive data source:

```
var NewChatters = new Meteor.Collection("null");
```

Template:

```
<template name="newChatDetails">
  <ul>
    {{#each newChatters}}
      <li>{{username}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

Event:

```
Template.contactsLayout.events({
  'click #contactItem': function (e) {
    NewChatters.insert({username: this.username});
  }
});
```

Helper:

```
Template.newChatDetails.helpers({
  newChatters: function() { return NewChatters.find(); }
});
```

Comment: didn't think of this. I'll prob just use the session object here per another answer below but this is another helpful approach, thanks

Comment: var NewChatters = new Meteor.Collection(null);   If you put null in quotes it just names your collection "null" and still syncs it with server.

Answer (score 3):

To mimick the behaviour of `Session` without polluting the `Session`, use a [`ReactiveVar`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar):

```
 Template.contactsLayout.created = function() {
      this.data.newChatters = new ReactiveVar([]);
 }

 Template.contactsLayout.events({
      'click #contactItem': function (event, template) {
            ...
            template.data.newChatters.set(
                template.data.newChatters.get().push(this.username)
            );
           ...
```

Then, in the inner template, use the parent reactive data source:

```
 Template.newChatDetails.helpers({
      newChatters: function() {
           return Template.parentData(1).newChatters.get();
      }
 });
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer. One suggestion, however, might be to move the reactive var outside of the template data object and simply into the template instance itself. This keeps the data object uncluttered.

Comment: @Adam No, you can't take this out from the `data` object, because that's exactly the trick that allows you to access parent data from a template: with the `parentData` method.

Comment: not natively, anyway... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27949407/how-to-get-the-parent-template-instance-of-the-current-template

Answer (score 1):

for people who is looking for a workaround for this in the year 2015+ (since the post is of 2014).

I'm implementing a posts wizard `pw_module` where I need to update data reactively depending on the *route parameters*:

```
Router.route('/new-post/:pw_module', function(){
    var pwModule = this.params.pw_module;
    this.render('post_new', {
        data: function(){
            switch (true) {
                case (pwModule == 'basic-info'):
                    return {
                        title: 'Basic info'
                    };
                    break;
                case (pwModule == 'itinerary'):
                    return {
                        title: 'Itinerary'
                    };
                    break;
                default:
            }
        }
    });
}, {
    name: 'post.new'
});
```

Later in the template just do a:

`<h1>{{title}}</h1>`

#### Changing routes

The navigation that updates the URL looks like this:

```
<nav>
    <a href="{{pathFor route='post.new' pw_module='basic-info'}}">Basic info</a>
    <a href="{{pathFor route='post.new' pw_module='itinerary'}}">Itinerary</a>
</nav>
```

Hope it still helps someone.