# Accessing other templates' instances

Tags: meteor

You can access the current template's instance by doing `Template.instance()`. But you often run into situations where you have to access other templates' instances as well. For example, if you use `ReactiveVar`, then you would want to get or set variables that are attached to other template instances.

I came across [How to get the parent template instance (of the current template)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27949407/how-to-get-the-parent-template-instance-of-the-current-template) but this is not complete.

**Q1. How can we access any template's instance, not just the current template's**

**Q2. Is it against the Meteor way if I need to access other templates' instances?**

Comment: As of this writing, blaze doesn't have a built-in component library, so you are stuck doing things like [Blaze.getData](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/blaze_getdata). If you have a concrete example I can give a more specific example with code.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to set your template variable directly at the template level instead of inside the instance.

```
Template.example.myVariable = new ReactiveVar();
```

instead of

```
Template.example.onCreated(function (){
  this.myVariable = new ReactiveVar();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest I got was to  target the template by one of its elements (assume the template contains a form)

```
Blaze.getView($('form')[0]).templateInstance().someReactiveVar.set('changed')
```

Answer (score 0):

If your target templates are in the same file, you can just define the reactive variable outside the template functions, at the beginning of the file. All templates in the file will access it.

If your target template is the parent template, (or any further parent template) you can access its *data context* using `Template.parentData()` the argument being the rank of the parent (default is 1). It seems that you know that already.

If you need to access a DOM element within a different template in the same page, you can use jQuery selectors.

I don't know any other way to reach another template instance (afaik, there is no `Blaze.getTemplate(name)` function.) The answer you are referring to seems to be the better you can get.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is purely subjective, since in Meteor there are so many different ways of doing things, but I actually think `Session` is perfectly suited for sharing variables across several templates. People argue that `Session` is bad since it's global and can pollute the namespace. I would argue that it's up to the developer to keep their environment clean in any way that works for them. So for instance, this is bad:

```
Session.set('count', 23);
Session.set('last', new Date());
```

But this is better:

```
Session.set('notifications/count', 23);
Session.set('notificatinos/last', new Date());
```