# Meteor: Access reactive dict variable in child template

Tags: javascript, meteor

I need to check in a child template the value of a reactive dict variable, which was created in the parent template.

```
<template name="parent">
    {{ > child }}
</template>

<template name="child">
    {{#if something}}
        checked
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

This is how I initialize a reactive dict variable to the parent template:

```
Template.parent.onCreated(function() {
    this.blabla = new ReactiveDict();
});
```

So for the parent template this helper is working:

```
Template.parent.helpers({
    anything: function(type) { return (Template.instance().blabla.get('foo') === 'bar') ? true : false; }
});
```

But it won't work for the child:

```
Template.child.helpers({
    something: function() { return (Template.instance().blabla.get('foo') === 'bar') ? true : false; }
});
```

So how can I check the value of the variable in the child helper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At its core, this question is about how to find a template's parent instance. I'd recommend reading all of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27949407/how-to-get-the-parent-template-instance-of-the-current-template).

I'll build on the idea presented by Sacha, with this example:

**html**

```
<template name="parent">
    {{ > child parentHelper=parentHelper}}
</template>

<template name="child">
  {{#if parentHelper}}
    <h1>pass</h1>
  {{else}}
    <h1>fail</h1>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

**js**

```
Template.parent.onCreated(function() {
    this.dict = new ReactiveDict();
    this.dict.set('foo', 'bar');
});

Template.parent.helpers({
  parentHelper: function() {
    return Template.instance().dict.equals('foo', 'bar');
  }
});
```

If that exact pattern doesn't work in your code, you can try one of the others from the linked question above.

Comment: That means I should define the helper for the parent template and not for the child template, right?

Comment: With this technique, yes. Will that work in your project?