# Meteor Blaze access Template.contentBlock inside Template.onCreated

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars, html-templates

I am writing a custom Blaze block helper with children:

```js
<template name="parent">
    {{> Template.contentBlock ..}}
</template>

<template name="child">
    {{> Template.contentBlock ..}}
</template>
```

My intended use case would be to have a Template with arbitrary child nodes, that I define in the html file.

```js
{{#parent}}

  {{#child id="child1" title="Child 1"}}
    <p>This is content of child 1</p>
  {{/child}}

  {{#child id="child2" title="Child 2"}}
    <p>This is content of child 2</p>
  {{/child}}

  {{#child id="childN" title="Child N"}}
    <p>This is content of child N</p>
  {{/child}}

{{/parent}}
```

No problem so far. However, in the parent Template's `onCreated` / `autorun` I want to have access to `child` templates. I want to use this data to dynamically create in the parent Template elements, based

```js
Template.parent.onCreated(function () {
    const instance = this;
    instance.state = new ReactiveDict();

    instance.autorun(function () {
        const contentBlocks = // how?
        instance.state.set("children", contentBlocks);
    });
});

Template.parent.helpers({
    children() {
        return Template.instance().state.get("children");
    }
});
```

Where `children` would be used in the `parent` template as following:

```js
{{#parent}}

  {{#each children}}
    do something with {{this.value}}
  {{/each}}      

  {{#child id="child1" title="Child 1"}}
    <p>This is content of child 1</p>
  {{/child}}

  {{#child id="child2" title="Child 2"}}
    <p>This is content of child 2</p>
  {{/child}}

  {{#child id="childN" title="Child N"}}
    <p>This is content of child N</p>
  {{/child}}

{{/parent}}
```

What I don't want is to access the contentBlock's content (the `<p>`) but rather get a list of the added `child` Templates.

Is that possible with the current Template / Blaze API? The [documentation](http://blazejs.org/api/spacebars.html#Custom-Block-Helpers) is a bit thin on that point.

It is basically the opposite of this post: [How to get the parent template instance (of the current template)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27949407/how-to-get-the-parent-template-instance-of-the-current-template)

---

**Edit 1: Use parent View's Renderfunction (only partially working)**

I found a way to get the `parent` Template's children but not their `data` reactively:

```js
// in Template.parant.onCreated -> autorun
const children = instance.view.templateContentBlock.renderFunction()
    .filter(child => typeof child === 'object')
    .map(el => Blaze.getData(el._render()));
console.log(children);
// null, null, null because Blaze.getData(view) does return null
```

Another approach I found is to used a shared `ReactiveVar` but both seem to me not clean enough. I just want to get the list of Template instances in the parent's js code.

---

**Edit 2: Use a shared ReactiveVar (only partially working)**

It is possible to use a shared `ReactiveVar` as long as it is in the scope of both Templates:

```js
const _cache = new ReactiveVar({});

Template.parent.onCreated(function () {
    const instance = this;
    instance.state = new ReactiveDict();

    instance.autorun(function () {
        const children = Object.values(_cache.get());
        instance.state.set("children", children);
    });
});

Template.parent.helpers({
    children() {
        return Template.instance().state.get("children");
    }
});
```

**Working** (but only rendered once, not reactive):

```js
Template.child.onCreated(function () {
    const instance = this;
    const data = Template.currentData();
    const cache = _cache.get();
    cache[data.id] = data;
    _cache.set(cache);
});
```

**Not working** (child autorun is setting values, but new values are not rendered):

```js
Template.child.onCreated(function () {
    const instance = this;
    instance.autorun(function() {
        const instance = this;
        const data = Template.currentData();
        const cache = _cache.get();
        cache[data.id] = data;
        _cache.set(cache);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here is what I came up with. Pls let me know if that is what you wanted or if I misunderstood.

main.html:

```
<body>
    {{> content}}
</body>

<template name="content">
    {{#parent}}

        {{#each children}}
            <p>do something with {{this.id}}</p>
            <p>data: {{this.tmpl.data.title}}</p>
        {{/each}}

        {{#child id="child1" title="Child 1" parentTemplate=this.parentTemplate}}
            <p>This is content of child 1</p>
        {{/child}}

        {{#child id="child2" title="Child 2" parentTemplate=this.parentTemplate }}
            <p>This is content of child 2</p>
        {{/child}}

        {{#child id="childN" title="Child N" parentTemplate=this.parentTemplate }}
            <p>This is content of child N</p>
        {{/child}}

    {{/parent}}
</template>

<template name="parent">
    {{> Template.contentBlock parentTemplate=template}}
</template>

<template name="child">
    {{> Template.contentBlock }}
</template>
```

main.js

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';

import './main.html';

Template.content.helpers({
    children() {
        return this.parentTemplate.children.get();
    },
});

Template.parent.onCreated(function () {
    this.children = new ReactiveVar([]);
});

Template.parent.helpers({
    template() {
        return Template.instance();
    }
});

Template.child.onRendered(function () {
    const children = this.data.parentTemplate.children.get();
    children.push({ id: this.data.id, tmpl: this });
    this.data.parentTemplate.children.set(children);
});
```

Output:

[image]

Although it uses `ReactiveVar` which is not ideal it does not rely on any global and you can put your code in different files, no problem.

Comment: I checked your solution. It is running fine, also with the required reactivity in the . But it also introduces a third template instance. For the fairness I will wait until the bounty period days.